# TinyMCE 5: Disabled editor but allow to copy text

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-plugins

How to disable the Editor but allow the user to copy the text?

When I set `disabled` to `true` it's now possible to select and copy text.

```
<Editor disabled={true} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

Just set the `contenteditable` attribute to `false` (you can delete the content).

```
// do not use this solution!
<Editor 
  init={{
    init_instance_callback: editor => {
      editor.getBody().setAttrib('contenteditable', false);
    }
  }}
/>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<Editor 
  init={{
    init_instance_callback: editor => {
      editor.setMode('readonly');
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Just a note that this does indeed still allow you to copy the content but it would also allow you to delete all the content.  If you use this example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56307277/tinymce-5-disabled-editor-but-allow-to-copy-text) click in the editor window and triple click on the content (to select it all) then press  DEL.  The content will be deleted.  This may not be an issue for you but I thought you should be aware that this is a side effect of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how TinyMCE's read only mode works - in that mode the editor is truly read only and will not allow you to select the text in the editor.  If you wanted different behavior you would need to suggest that to the TinyMCE developers via their GitHub Issue Tracker:

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues